# Allow FORM submit on ENTER when focus is not in an input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I have a focusable `div` using `tabindex="0"`. Everything works fine, except for the possibility to submit the `form` on `enter` key. It does work when the `input` is focused, but doesn't when the `div` has the focus.

I know I could use some javascript to capture the `enter` key and submit the closest `form`, but are there any other ways to overcome this?

Here is a little fiddle to demonstrate the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/ajqfm3Lb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid HTML, strictly speaking, but it works... You can put your `div` inside a `<button type="submit">` and remove the button's default styling. Like the other answer that was given, the `div` must be inside the `form` for this work without additional JavScript. You'd also no longer need the tabindex on the div.

```
<form>
<input/>
<button type="submit">
<div>
</div>
</button>
</form>
```

and

```
button[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g2j2c0ra/2/

Comment: Thank you, nice idea, although I won't apply it I think :) I'll rather go with the javascript approach. However, this is something I was asking for, so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, instead of submitting the "closest form", you could actually check the Enter keypress for any element *within* that form. I realize that this is somewhat similar to the solution you *weren't* looking for, but I'm not sure if you're aware that you can tie that keypress event to specifically the form.

Check it out:

https://jsfiddle.net/ajqfm3Lb/9/

```
$("form").on("keypress", "*:not(textarea)", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("submitted");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This event only fires when a key is pressed *while focus is on the form*, because the `keypress` event is only tied to the selector `$("form")`. The `e.which == 13` just checks enter, specifically.

Of course, you could modify `$("form")` to be any selector (eg, the form's 
ID, class, etc).

**EDIT:** As you pointed out, simply listening for the "enter" press on a form would cause issues with elements that require its use, like `textarea`. I've used Event Delegation to trigger the event on all children of form *except* `textarea`.

Let me know how this works.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I was aware of the direct binding. Also, doesn't it interfere with `textarea`'s enter key?

Comment: Very true, I hadn't realized `textarea` would be involved but I should've pointed that out. How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/ajqfm3Lb/9/

Answer (score 0):

Just give your form a name (eg `id="test`") and then use the following code to submit only the form with the given id:

```
$(function(){
 $("#test").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('submitted');
        return false
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Please note that `e.keyCode` will not work in all browsers. In vanilla JS, `e.which` won't either, however jQuery actually standardizes `e.which` so it works in all browsers.